# Ошибка внесения человека в черный список

Tags: python, mysql, sql, discord.py, pymysql

Появилась неизвестная ошбика, которая не дает мне занести человека в черный список.

Технически, после ввода данной команды в mysql должен поступить айди аккаунта. Но вместо этого, программа выдает следующее

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/redwest/PycharmProjects/ReddBot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/redwest/PycharmProjects/ReddBot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1348, in invoke
    await ctx.invoked_subcommand.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/redwest/PycharmProjects/ReddBot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Users/redwest/PycharmProjects/ReddBot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
Ignoring exception in command blacklist add:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/redwest/PycharmProjects/ReddBot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/redwest/PycharmProjects/ReddBot/cogs/owner.py", line 110, in blacklist_add
    if userID in bl[i]['id']:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Сам код

```py
@blacklist.command(name="add")
    async def blacklist_add(self, context, member: discord.Member = None):
        for i in range(len(result)):
            if context.message.author.id == result[i]['id']:
                userID = member.id
                try:
                    for i in range(len(bl)):
                        if userID in bl[i]['id']:
                            embed = discord.Embed(
                                title="Ошибка",
                                description=f"**{member.name}** уже в чс",
                                color=0xE02B2B
                            )
                            await context.send(embed=embed)
                            return
                    with db.cursor() as curs:
                        sqladd = "INSERT INTO blacklisted (id) VALUES (%s)"
                        valadd = (userID)
                        curs.execute(sqladd, valadd)
                        db.commit()
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title="Аккаунт занесен в ЧС",
                        description=f"**{member.name}** успешно занесен в чс",
                        color=0x42F56C
                    )
                    await context.send(embed=embed)
                except AttributeError:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title="Ошибка!",
                        description=f"Не веденно имя пользователя",
                        color=0xE02B2B
                    )
                    await context.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                if result[i]['id'] is None:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title="Ошибка",
                        description="У вас недостаточно прав на данную команду",
                        color=0xE02B2B
                    )
                    await context.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if userID in bl[i]['id']:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Я так понимаю, в `bl[i]['id']` у вас значение типа `int`, т.е. какое-то число. А конструкция `x in y` проверяет, что элемент `x` входит в **коллекцию** `y`. Поскольку число - это не коллекция, питон не понимает, как его перебирать (`is not iterable`). В общем, вам скорее всего нужно проверять просто равенство:

```
if userID == bl[i]['id']:
```